# Persisting Powershell variables between steps

Tags: powershell, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Am working on VSTS release task for deploying the Web Application along with Database. Unfortunately, we are not creating any Build Definition for creating drop folder. But, my client will provide drop folder for this project, what I need is “I want to copy the files in VM along with creation of System-Timed folder” at release level. For that I created a folder with the help of PowerShell Task.

```
$FileName = (Get-Date).tostring("dd-MM-yyyy-hh-mm-ss")

$Fname = New-Item -itemType Directory -Path C:\Database -Name ("Test "+ $FileName)

Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=$Fname;]$Fname"

Write-Output ("##vso[task.setvariable variable=$Fname;]UpdatedValueInScript")
```

But, I’m not able to use that the above PowerShell Script output variable in next “Copy Files” task.

Note: For creating folder in VM, I followed this [link](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md)

Comment: The "next" task must be within the *same phase*.

Comment: @gvee  It is already in the same phase, but I don't know the how to use it

Comment: `Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=Fname;]$Fname"` <- don't use a dynamic variable name.

Comment: @gvee Thanks,now my issue was resolved.

Comment: @Mani You can accept gvee's reply as answer.

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT Yah,Iam accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable name should be static.

The *value* should change.

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=Fname;]$Fname"
```